# How to delete a row with primary key id?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table user. It has 3 columns id(set as primary and Is Identity as Yes), name and password. When I enter data to the table the id became incremented. But on delete query only name and password will be deleted. I need to delete a particular row including the id.
For example:

```
id:1 name:abc password:123
id:2 name:wer password:234
id:3 name:lkj password:222
id:4 name:new password:999
```

I need to  delete the third column ie, **id:3 name:lkj password:222** . But after deleting this row, the table should be shown as below.

```
id:1 name:abc password:123
id:2 name:wer password:234
id:3 name:new password:999
```

Comment: Are you saying that `delete from the_table where id = 42` did not remove that row?

Comment: Can you post your delete query

Comment: At a guess, are you expecting the `id` value you have just deleted to become available again when you insert a new row? If so, that's not how `identity` fields work. Once a number has been used, it's gone (without some mucking around with the table).

Comment: I have edited my question. Please reply me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the additional information you have provided it shows you do not understand the `IDENTITY` data type. As others, including myself, have said numbers are not re-used.

You should also avoid changing primary keys just because a row was deleted.

It would seem you need a row number, don't use the key for this. Create a view using the [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, something like

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by id) AS row_number, name, password, ...
FROM [Your_Table]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Tony said, once a number has been used, it isn't available anymore. A workaround for this problem is the following:
1. Don't use an Identity field at all. Use just an integer field set as primary key.
2. Declare a trigger which is triggered whenever a new row is inserted.
3. This trigger has to read the the `ID` of the last inserted row in the table and increment it by one and insert the result in the `ID` field.
So when you delete this row later, the ID is available again.

Comment: The problem with this is that you absolutely kill any performance doing this. There is no way to do that nicely without tons of locking - and in absoluztely most cases the ID field requiring this is a design error. This may be nice for a user / password table, but for a more transactionally active table it is going to be one of thos pieces of softawre that are dead slow as all access to the table has to be serialized.

Comment: @TomTom for every solution there are some advantages and disadvantages. Finally you cannot rollback with identity fields. If you want to have that value, you haven't to use them at all. This is just a way to go around the problem, but it has its disadvantages: performance and maintenance. You have to look at the specific case you are dealing with in your application and database. Then you can decide which solution fits you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the id later, that is an extremely poor idea. Don;t go down that path. The only ways to do that are either performance problems or are very subject to error when you have race conditions. There is a reason why udntities don't reuse values after all. The id should be meaningless anyway. There is usually no reason why it can't skip values except personal preference. But personal preference should not take precendence over performance and reliability. If you want to dothis because you hate the skipped values then don't. If you are getting this requirement from above, then push back. Tell them that the alternative are more time-consuming and less reliable and far more likely to cause data integrity problems.